# __attribute__((weak)) doesn't work

Tags: linux, gcc, weak

I have wrote below code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

int pthread_create(
        pthread_t*,
        const pthread_attr_t *,
        void* (*)(void *),
        void*)  __attribute__ ((weak))  ;


int main(){
    if (pthread_create) {
        printf("multi-thread");
    } else {
        printf("single-thread");
    }
}
```

When compiling the code with different ways and running it, it shows the same consequence . The codes are undermentioned:

```
zoushengfu@zoushengfudeMacBook-Pro:~/Documents/code/c++$ gcc -o pt
pthread.cpp  
zoushengfu@zoushengfudeMacBook-Pro:~/Documents/code/c++$ ./pt 
multi-thread
zoushengfu@zoushengfudeMacBook-Pro:~/Documents/code/c++$ gcc -o pt pthread.cpp -lpthread
zoushengfu@zoushengfudeMacBook-Pro:~/Documents/code/c++$ ./pt
multi-thread
```

I want to know why the result is same wheather I use library **pthread** when compile it. And do I some error when using  **__attribute__((weak))**

Comment: Maybe `gcc` is configured in a way that the `-lpthread` switch is used by default. Do you get a linker error when you remove the "weak" declaration?

Comment: How to know weather -lpthread is used by default or not? When I emove the "weak" declaration, it show below :zoushengfu@zoushengfudeMacBook-Pro:~/Documents/code/c++$ gcc -o pt pthread.cpp -lpthread
pthread.cpp:12:9: warning: address of function 'pthread_create' will always
      evaluate to 'true' [-Wpointer-bool-conversion]
    if (pthread_create) {
    ~~  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pthread.cpp:12:9: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this
      warning
    if (pthread_create) {
        ^
        &
1 warning generated.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works for me with `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04) 5.4.1 20160904`.
Please post build logs with `--verbose` compilation.

Comment: It is too long and can not show bellow